# How can I do subdirectory manipulation in shell?

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal, command, directory-structure

For example, running a command on n-number of sorted subdirectories, where n is an input.
Or
how can I run a for loop on a range of subdirectories where I can give that range as an input? Like the following except how can I define the range here?

```
for d in ["sd1"-"sd2"] do ( cd "$d" && do stuff ) done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brace expansion if you have a shell that supports it:

```
for d in sd{1..2}; do
    ( cd "$d" && dostuff )
done
```

With `zsh`, `ksh93` or `yash -o braceexpand` (but not `bash`), you can do

```
n=4
for d in sd{1..$n}; do
    ( cd "$d" && dostuff )
done
```

Related question: [Can I use variables inside {} expansion without `eval`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117144/can-i-use-variables-inside-expansion-without-eval)

A variation on this would be

```
for (( i=1; i<=n; ++i )); do
  str="sd$i"
  ( cd ... )
done
```

This is the C-style `for` loop supported by `bash` and other shells (still an extension to the POSIX standard though).

Comment: "1..2"- are they index here or part of the label? Like say if the range was my_directory_111 to my_directory_121, would it be:
`for d in my_directory_{111..121}; do
    ( cd "$d" && dostuff )
done`

Comment: @0x1 Part of the text. `{2..3}` expands to `2 3`. Test with `echo  my_directory_{111..121}`.

Comment: Awesome! This works! What if the subdirectories are dates? How do I input dates? `2016-01-0{1..2}` This works temporarily, but when it gets greater than 9, I cannot generalize it anymore without changing the command. Is there any suggestion there?

Comment: @0x1, with dates is much more complicated. You can use `date` command to generate dates

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas! `ksh93` and `bash` is what I use and know.

Comment: @0x1 That's a different kettle of fish altogether. Warrants a new question.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
for d (sd<1-10>(Nn-/)) (cd $d && dostuff)
```

- `<1-10>` is a glob operator that matches decimal integer numbers between 1 and 10. It will match on `1`, `001`... You can make it `<->` to match any positive decimal integer number.
- `(Nn-/)` is a glob  qualifier.

  - `N` to not fail if there's no match
  - `n` to sort the elements numerically (so `sd10` comes after `sd2`)
  - `-/` to only include files of type directory (after  symlink resolution).

If you wanted to list directories between two dates, where the date is encoded in the directory's name (like `sd2017-08-01`):

```
for d (sd<->-<->-<->(Nne{'
  [[ ! $REPLY < sd2015-06-06 && ! $REPLY > sd2017-08-09 ]]'}-/))
  (cd $d && dostuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

Other possibe solution is to use `seq` command (where is available)

```
for i in `seq -f "sd%03.0f" 111 121`
do
( cd "$i" && do stuff )
done
```

Comment: What does "03.0f" mean here? Sorry I am new to bash. Is it telling about the range will be 3 floating point?

Comment: 03.0f is the format of the numbers. leading zero, 3 digits, zero digits after comma (integer)

Comment: @0x1 "zero-filled to tree positions with no numbers after the decimal comma". See the `printf(3)` manual (`man 3 printf`).

Comment: @RomeoNinov For dates `seq -f "2016-01-%02.0f" 1 31` this worked so far. Just have to figure out a way for different months and years. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Glob expansions are sorted, which means you can do something like:

```
state=0
for d in *; do
   case $d in "sd1") state=1;; "sd2") break;; esac
   if [ 1 -eq "$state" ]; then
      ( cd "$d" && dostuff )
   fi
done
```

I'm assuming here that `sd1` and `sd2` aren't real examples  and that the range can't be described with trivial numerical ranges. If they can, I'd use [Romeo Ninov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/101265/romeo-ninov)'s [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387821/23692).

Brace expansions are very neat, but unfortunately, many POSIX shells don't have them, as they're not a POSIX requirement.

Comment: They are sorted, but they are sorted _lexically_ by default, that is where `sd10` comes before `sd2`.